# can't align -moz-box for firefox/IE

Tags: css

i'm having some trouble in aligning -moz-box to display properly in firefox and IE. i can do it properly for chrome/opera by changing '-webkit-box-pack' to center/end etc and it works perfectly but the '-moz-box-pack' is not changing anything

here is the link of a sample page of my site http://www.awforum.co.nf/register

```
   body{
       background-color:#EAEAEA;
       width:100;
       display:-moz-box;
       display:-webkit-box;
       -moz-box-pack: center;
       -webkit-box-pack:center;
       //-moz-box-align:center;
       //-webkit-box-align:center;
       text-align: center;         
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you try to use an old way/syntaxe of the flex-box model.

it would be today morelike :

```
body{
    background-color:#EAEAEA;
    width:100;
    display:-webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-pack:center;
    -webkit-box-align:center;   
    text-align: center;
    background-color:#EAEAEA;
    display:-webkit-flex;
    display:-ms-flexbox;
    display:flex;
    -webkit-box-align:center;
    -webkit-align-items:center;
        -ms-flex-align:center;
            align-items:center;
   -webkit-box-pack:center;
   -webkit-justify-content:center;
       -ms-flex-pack:center;
           justify-content:center;
}
```